# Как сделать карусель товаров на главной OpenCart?

Tags: opencart, owl-carousel, карусель, слайдер, carousel

OpenCart **3.0.2.0**, натягиваю верстку на движок, встал вопрос в использовании слайдера, мне нужен слайдер товаров на главной стр, с пагинацией, 2 дня уже ищу хоть какой-нибудь БЕСПЛАТНЫЙ слайдер товаров, но все они либо для **oc 2v** либо платные, помогите пожалуйста, может кто-то уже сталкивался с этим? Как я понял Owl Carousel нет для opencart, находил вроде что-то в даркнете, но опять же все платное, Хэлп

Comment: В чем проблема самому написать?

Comment: Например [вот ссылка на самую примитивную реализацию](http://plnkr.co/edit/mmB7VI860TmlheRj7jlm?p=preview).  Ещё нужно погуглить запрос к бд на OpenCart

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я не знаю как писать модули для oc

Comment: А при чем тут ОС? Для клиента на js напишите. Либо чего вы хотите? Чтобы кто то для вас написал? Так это не на этот форум...

Comment: @ВитайлийШебаниц, да написать это могу, но тогда как вывести товары из определенной категории на главную страницу? И как сделать слайдер грамотно? Как обернуть каждый товар в div. Как вообще это делается на ос?

Comment: Вывести с базы: ajax в помощь. Грамотно - это типо нормально отобразить на клиенте? Можете сами попробовать, можете воспользоваться фреймверком (к примеру bootstrap)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц на пример кода вывода могу рассчитывать?

Comment: Да из куча в инете...просто в Гугле введите "основы ajax". Или на SO гляньте, я думаю тоже найдете.